# Microservices with REST API and messaging

Tags: rest, messaging, microservices

Is it ok to have a microservice exposing a public REST API to a gateway but also communicate with other services through messaging?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. BTW, "public" means that this endpoint is visible to anyone and you want to be visible only to the Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

At least add some kind of identifier which is known only by the gateway or check the IP address if it is dedicated to the gateway. I hope you are using an encrypted communication protocol. Can't you do this via VPN, SSH tunnel or something more secure?